# Google Apps SSO into ASP.Net Web Application

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, saml

I would be very grateful if you could shed some light on the problem I have.

I have a web-application, which is using 2-Factor Authentication, the 1st one being AD username & Password. Now this web-app is internet hosted and doesn't reside on any internal domain. It connects to an AD domain via LDAP.

In this same application, we want users to be able to send & receive their Gmail emails but with SSO. We don't want them to re-enter a username & password for their gmail account. Instead, the user's can store their Gmail username in a User attribute(like Description) in Active Directory.

Both the Identity Server and our web-app will be on same internet hosted server but will not be part of any AD domain as both our web-app and Identity Server will be used for multiple domains.

Identity Server should be able to receive Domain Details and Service Account details for a particular domain from our web-app.

When user logs into our web-app, an automatic SSO request for Google goes to the Identity Server with info for the domain, the user belongs to. SSO request gets filled and a session is built. Then user should be able to see Gmail Emails, Contacts, Calendar, etc. in our web-app only.

I don't know if this is possible at all.

Any suggestions for this or do achieve similar functionality will be much appreciated.

Comment: +1 for that wonderfully literary opening.

Comment: You even have "saml" as one of tags, haven't you really tried to implement a custom identity server and federate your google apps with it? This is definitely possible. I am not quite sure what your problem is - would you like to know if your scenario is possible or rather you search for information on what specific tech stack you should use for asp.net?

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. I have two questions now:

Comment: 1) So, will I have to create an Identity Server from Scratch or are there any modifiable solutions? 2) Also, I know of the SAML concept for assertion to get authentication tokens, but not sure about where to start in coding for it. 3) Moreover, I have no idea how SSO works with Office 365 and SharePoint. 4) Also, we want this whole SSO to be done in the background. Once SSO is done, we to retrieve stuff like Email, Calendar Info, to our own application and use it there.